# node-postgres transaction using in promise chain and all

Tags: transactions, promise, chain, node-postgres

https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions
I tried to implement some transaction APIs for my project using pg, following the above documentation.
But one thing pops out of my mind, can one connection(client) hold two transactions in parallel?

For example, I create one transaction by query('BEGIN'), and within this transaction, I will have a promiseChain1, where in each step, a sql will be executed. the last step is to do a query('COMMIT'), and catch(err=>query('ROLLBACK'))

psuedo code:
**BEGIN.then(SQL1_1).then(SQL1_2).then(SQL1_3).then(COMMIT).catch(ROLLBACK)**

And I will create another transaction by query('BEGIN') again, and similar to the previous one, another promiseChain2 will be created, similar to the previous one. 
pseudo code:
**BEGIN.then(SQL2_1).then(SQL2_2).then(COMMIT).catch(ROLLBACK)**

The last thing I will do is to call Promise.all([promiseChain1, promiseChain2]).then(...)

depending on the time of each sql statement execution takes, order of the two BEGINs, two COMMITs/ROLLBACKs and other sql statements from both chains may be random, right?

```
BEGIN
SQL1_1
        BEGIN
SQL1_2
        SQL2_1
        SQL2_2
        COMMIT
SQL1_3
ROLLBACK
```

But since two "transactions" are actually using the same connection, I think the result will be very different than what I expect.

Can anyone clarify if this will be a problem using pg's transaction concept with promise chain and all?

Comment: The simple answer is no, you cannot do it. The logic of the two transactions will overlap. You need two separate connections to execute two transactions in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a client is a pool of connections for particular client credential. And you begin a transaction with seperate asynchronous flow , it will work without affecting others. If both are **isolated promise chain** Both will use seperate connection on pool if available or wait for new connection available.

[image]